# Does azure block INCOMING port 25 to VM?

Tags: linux, azure

Added 443 and 25 to allow for inbound rule to VM
[image: Added 443 and 25 to allow for inbound rule to VM]

```
iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

Setup a listener on the vm

```
sudo nc -l 25
```

From external computer

```
telnet myVMip 25
```

Connection times out.

When doing the same procedure for 443 it works fine.  This leads me to believe port 25 is blocked by azure itself?

Comment: Are you sure? It's more likely to be your ISP.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - Duh.  Forgot about that.  You're right.  Guess I'll leave this here in case it helps anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to troubleshoot this issue is usage of the traceroute with tcp packets. Use this command to check where the packets are blocked:

```
traceroute -T -p 25 -n <myVMip>
```

The next step - run the tcpdump on the VM and check incoming packets. The tcpdump captures packets **before** firewall.

```
tcpdump -ni <iface> 'port 25'
```

So, if you see the packets in the dump, but nothing works, then check the firewall. By default the iptables command lists only the `filter` table. Better use the `iptables-save -c` command to show the full rule set with rule counters.

Then check, the port is really listened. Use the `netstat -tlnp` or `ss -tlnp 'sport == :25'` commands. You should see the listened socket and your program.

If all steps above are done, but the service doesn't work, run the `strace -p <pid>` command to check, the service really gets data from sockets.